# Proc_common_v_3 not found

Tags: xilinx

I am starting out getting more hands-on with FPGAs and have chosen Xilinx.
In a small trial project I have the problem that XST complains about the library proc_common_v_3 is not found. The ise prj file contains paths looking like "../../.." and so on and it gets recreated when trying to change the paths.
When looking in the project list and not the file, the library is referenced using "........", which is different.

Is there another way to make sure ISE handles libraries correct?
ISE Version 14.7
Error message when doing XST->Check Syntax
Xst:2927 - .... line 1: Source file ../../../../../../../../../../../../../Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK/hw/XilinxProcessorIPLib/pcores/proc_common_v3_00_a/hdl/vhdl/proc_common_pkg.vhd does not exist

NB: Yes I know there is a thread on this issue, but my comment gets deleted. The answer there is using what seems to be known working paths, but as starting out that is not possible. Better to go for Altera perhaps.

Thanks in advance.

-Michael

Comment: Use the environment variable pointing to you Xilinx installation.

Comment: Actually decided to not tamper with the installation as it is supposed to work without user intervention. Go with Vivado is my take on a solution using Zynq.